# Problem html css bootstrap My text does not appear completely

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have Problem in my PopUp
in the bootstrap My text does not appear completely

this is my code

```
                          <div class="row min-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 colPlace">
                                    <span>test</span><span>*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 colPlace">

                                    <input class="form-control fieldSize" type="text">

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

css of colPlace

```
.colPlace {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

css of min-row

```
.min-row{
        margin-bottom: 13px;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

You can see the error
when I have to change the length of the text
the popup change his length but not as required
And you can see the span of disappearing under div of input

Comment: what does not appear exactly? I can see everything: https://codepen.io/polinq/pen/wvBoPGw

Comment: hello, I have edited my post

Comment: I think the code you provided is incomplete, please update it